# MQTT. Last Will and Testament on modem sim800c

Tags: mqtt, gsm, at-command

There was a question about the operation of the SIM800C modem via MQTT. Is it possible to set up a Last Will and Testament (LWT) message on this modem? Based on the [examples](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament/#:%7E:text=How%20do%20you%20specify%20a%20LWT%20message%20for%20a%20client%3F), in order to set up a will message, you need to send a topic and a message when connecting to the server.
The problem is that there are no tags with a topic and a message for the will in the API for this modem. (In other versions of the module, this has already been implemented. For example, SIM7080G has these tags).
[image]

Perhaps someone faced this problem? Perhaps there is another way to tell the server the settings for the will?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem.
SIM800C doesn't seem to have Last Will and Testament capability in the built-in MQTT stack.

What you should do is use TCP commands to establish network connectivity and use MQTT Library for embedded devices for the purpose of serialization-deserialization. You can use one of the following library : MQTTPacket or MQTTClient-c; depending on your enviroment.